# Is there any solution for typescript to disable type definitions for one special library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I installed one package with npm and this include an outdated d.ts file,
i want to overide this with a new d.ts file with something like:

```
declare module "package" {
    const Package: any;
    export = Package;
}
```

i want to use any type to avoid any checks.
thank you for your help.

typescript compiler should avoid the original d.ts file on package folder and read first our new d.ts file with "any" type declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

just create a new d.ts file like package_name.d.ts and add this line in tsconfig.json file as following:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ......

    "types" : ["./path_to/package.d.ts"]

    ......
},
```

the content of package.d.ts should be as:

```
declare module "package" {
    const Package: any;
    export = Package;
}
```

this should avoid type checking for a certain third party package.
enjoy!